# IntelliJ - redundancy of variables

Tags: java, intellij-idea, redundancy

I'm working on a lesson to create a vacation plan. When I write code like

```
double money1 =  money / days;
money1 =  money*100;
money1 = (int) money1/ 100.0;
```

IntelliJ underlines `money / days` and notifies me that it's redundant.

[image]

Why does it happen? How can I make it not redundant?

Comment: What error are you getting? What is your expected output?

Comment: THe output should be :

How many days are you going to spend traveling? 14

How much money, in USD, are you planning to spend on your trip? 2300

What is the three letter currency symbol for your travel destination?MXC

How many MXC are there in 1 USD? 19.8

If you are traveling for 14 that is the same as 336 hours or 20160 minutes

If you are going to spend $2300 USD that means per day you can spend up to 164.28 USD

(/sorry, I don;t know how to correcly format the answer)

Comment: Yet another `"I've searched everywhere..."` type question. Please avoid such worthless statements and instead **show** exactly what you **have** found. Those statements don't help clarify your problem, but your showing what you've found and how it doesn't help you **does**.

Comment: So your logic is wrong and you want someone to fix it?

Comment: Hey guys, I'm new here, It's the first time I make a question here. Sorry for something.

Comment: Yes, you should probably go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Better to do this *before* asking your first question, but better late than never.

Comment: I hope It's better now. I was just excited, sorry. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: At `double money1 =  money / days;` your IDE says `money / days;` is redundant because immediately after it you execute `money1 = money * 100;` which replaces previously calculated value with new value. Since you never used previous value calculating it doesn't make much sense. So `double money1 =  money / days;` is effectively the same as `double money1;`

Comment: I've modified it so:
        `double money1 = (money / days) * 100;` ,
        `money1= (int) money1;` ,
        `money1/= 100.0;` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ***immediately*** reassigning the variable, so your calculation is lost.

Observe:

```
double money1 =  money / days;
money1 =  money*100; // <- Quotient is discarded and overwritten
money1 = (int) money1/ 100.0; <- Prior product is discarded and overwritten
```

This is what IntelliJ is warning you about; this smells very much like a bug.  I can't reliably tell you *which* of these statements to change since they do very different things, but this is something you should look to debug in your logical flow.

Comment: I've found the mistake, I used _int_ instead of _double_ when asking for the input, so:
replaced:  `int money = input.nextInt();` for: `double money =input.nextDouble();`Also, fixed the part of the code that you said to:


        `double money1 = (money / days) * 100;`
        `money1= (int) money1;`
        `money1/= 100.0;`